# angular-gettext and translating strings in ternary conditions

Tags: angularjs, angular-gettext

Before I start rewriting my code:

Using angular-gettext, is there anyway to deal with these type of inline ternary condition? Applying the translate filter doesn't seem to be an option here...

```
<a uib-tooltip="{{favourite?'remove from favourites':'add to favourites'}}" ng-click="someaction()">something</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just move the strings to the controller (see the [ng-gettext docs](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate-js/)):

```
angular.module("someApp").controller("someController", ['gettext', function (gettext) {
    $scope.favoriteRemove = gettext("remove from favorites"),
    $scope.favoriteAdd = gettext("add to favorites");
}]);
```

> HTML

```
<a uib-tooltip="{{favourite?favoriteRemove:favoriteAdd}}" ng-click="someaction()">something</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think your right. I was just hoping there was an inline solution that I had overlooked... or a clever way to use the filter anyway:-)

Comment: I think the filter is not an issue here - it should work once you have the translated strings. But the gettext extractor will get confused by a ternary expression.